# In 14.04, how do I print the current keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have several keyboard entry languages set up, and can easily select the one I want to use from the indicator menu. Once a language is chosen, the menu item "Keyboard Layout Chart" shows me what key generates what. How do I print the keyboard layout chart in Ubuntu 14.04? There is no Print button on the chart and there is no menu associated with the layout chart window. Perhaps this is a but in 14.04?

Comment: Try the PrintScreen button on your physical keyboard.

Comment: That prints the entire screen as a graphic. In previous Ubuntu, I could get a print dialog for printing just the keyboard layout. Also, going the screenshot route involves extra steps and lower quality (I've done this using the Screenshot tool in the "current window" mode).

Answer (score 4):

The basic idea should be to use [`xkbprint`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xkbprint.1.html):

```
xkbprint :0 -o one.ps  
ps2pdf one.ps
evince one.pdf
```

The step through `ps2pdf` is needed here because otherwise the generated postscript is troublesome to view.

In principle it should be possible to add all the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> combinations to the map, but I never found the exact incantation to obtain it --- I mean, the neat map with 4 symbols per key.

Comment: Interesting. I had not known about xkbprint. I guess the trick is to type the first command, switch to the desired keyboard just before hitting Enter and then switch back to En for the remaining commands. I tried that with the Mk (Macedonian) keyboard layout and it almost worked. But the keys were labeled, for example, with things like "Macedonia_GJE" instead of the actual character, Ѓ  in this case. I tried adding "-label symbols" but that produced the same result.

Comment: Yep --- I struggled to. Try to play with the `-lc`  (locale) parameter, the font and the `-pict` options... and if you succeed definitely post an answer!